# Problem with SSAO

Tags: xna, rendering, post-processing, ssao

I'm trying to implement SSAO based on [this](http://theorangeduck.com/page/pure-depth-ssao) tutorial (and other). My setup:

- XNA 4.0
- Deferred
- depth = z/w

This is result:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Lines across buildings are moving when I move camera.
So I'm wondering is this problem in code or in parameters?

Here is code:

```
    float3 normal_from_depth(float depth0, float2 texcoords) {

    const float2 offset1 = float2(0.0, 0.001);
    const float2 offset2 = float2(0.001, 0.0);

    float depth1 = dot(tex2D(depth, texcoords + offset1).rgb, byte_to_float);
    float depth2 = dot(tex2D(depth, texcoords + offset2).rgb, byte_to_float);

    float3 p1 = float3(offset1, depth1 - depth0);
    float3 p2 = float3(offset2, depth2 - depth0);

    float3 normal = cross(p1, p2);
    //normal.z = -normal.z;

    return normalize(normal);
}

float4 Ssao(VSIO input) : COLOR0
{
    const float total_strength = 1.0;
    const float base = 0.2;

    const float area = 0.75;
    const float falloff = 0.000001;

    const float radius = 0.002;

    const int samples = 16;
    float3 sample_sphere[samples] = {
        float3(0.5381, 0.1856, -0.4319), float3(0.1379, 0.2486, 0.4430),
        float3(0.3371, 0.5679, -0.0057), float3(-0.6999, -0.0451, -0.0019),
        float3(0.0689, -0.1598, -0.8547), float3(0.0560, 0.0069, -0.1843),
        float3(-0.0146, 0.1402, 0.0762), float3(0.0100, -0.1924, -0.0344),
        float3(-0.3577, -0.5301, -0.4358), float3(-0.3169, 0.1063, 0.0158),
        float3(0.0103, -0.5869, 0.0046), float3(-0.0897, -0.4940, 0.3287),
        float3(0.7119, -0.0154, -0.0918), float3(-0.0533, 0.0596, -0.5411),
        float3(0.0352, -0.0631, 0.5460), float3(-0.4776, 0.2847, -0.0271)
    };

    //float3 random = normalize(tex2D(noise, input.uv * 4.0).rgb);

    float depth0 = dot(tex2D(depth, input.uv).rgb, byte_to_float);

    float3 position = float3(input.uv, depth0);
    float3 normal = normal_from_depth(depth0, input.uv);

    float radius_depth = radius / depth0;
    float occlusion = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < samples; i++) {

        float3 ray = radius_depth * sample_sphere[i];
        float3 hemi_ray = position + sign(dot(ray, normal)) * ray;

        float occ_depth = dot(tex2D(depth, saturate(hemi_ray.xy)).rgb, byte_to_float);
        float difference = depth0 - occ_depth;

        occlusion += step(falloff, difference) * (1.0 - smoothstep(falloff, area, difference));
    }

    float ao = 1.0 - total_strength * occlusion * (1.0 / samples);
    return float4(ao, ao, ao, 1.f);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess it's something wrong with your normal buffer. Render out the normal buffer to screen and make sure it's in view space. (or world if the depth is so)